# Can Regex capture a certain string only if a condition is met?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

**I have this set of data:**

- EndDate":"2024-10-24","Employee":"000A0001","Submitted":"N"
- EndDate":"2023-10-18","Employee":"000A0001","Submitted":"P"
- EndDate":"2021-01-02","Employee":"000A0001","Submitted":"J"
- EndDate":"2022-10-11","Employee":"000A0001","Submitted":"M"
- EndDate":"2020-09-18","Employee":"000A0001","Submitted":"N"

I only want to capture the **EndDate** that has a Submitted value of **N or M**.

**The captured EndDate should be:**

- 2024-10-24
- 2022-10-11
- 2020-09-18

Comment: try to show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a regex positive lookahead:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?=.+"Submitted":"[NM]")
```

More detail here: [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Comment: thanks a lot! this worked! I am new to regex, this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the date and use a look ahead:

```
"EndDate":"([^"]+)"(?=.*"Submitted":"[NM]")
```

You enddates are in group 1 of the match.

Note: I added '"' to the start of the regex assuming that you accidentally omitted it from the examples that appear to be json.